# How can I change a file field description?

Tags: 7

How can I change the file field description without altering a module file?

The function I would like to modify is [`theme_file_upload_help()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!file!file.field.inc/function/theme_file_upload_help/7).

Answer (score 0):

I have accomplished similar by using a [hook_form_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) in a custom module and altering the field's `#description` property.

Comment: This would only change the field in one specific form, i would like to change it in every existing form.

Comment: `hook_form_alter()` affects every single form and is suitable for changing the field everywhere it appears. If you wanted only one form you would use `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()`.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a theme function you want to override, then the way to do that is to write a function called `mytheme_file_upload_help` (if your theme is called `mytheme`).

so in your `mytheme/template.php` file:

```
function mytheme_file_upload_help($variables) {
   ... your code here
}
```